# How can I make new line string of Props used in react?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm having trouble with new line breaks in strings.

parent

```
<SampleComponent title="One \n Two \n Three">
```

children

```
type SampleComponentProps = {
  title: string;
};

export const SampleComponent: FC<SampleComponentProps> = ({
  title,
}) => {

  return (
     <div style={whiteSpace:'pre-line'}>{title}</div>
  );
};
```

display

```
One \n Two \n Three
```

I would expect

```
One
Two
Three
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work

```
return ({title.split("\\n").map((line, index) => (
    <React.Fragment key={index}>
      {line}
      <br />
    </React.Fragment>
  ))})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by setting HTML directly from React, just using html and css, no using JS regex, or convert string to array then output.

```html
<div
  style={{whiteSpace: 'pre'}}
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: ' One \n Two \n Three' }}
></div>
```

this is the result

[image]

Reference link: [dangerously set innerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)